HTTP Socket timeout in AWS CRT client with long HTTP calls
I am experiencing a HTTP socket timeout while using AwsCrtAsyncHttpClient. This occurs only when the HTTP call takes a long time, approximately 12-15 minutes. I am streaming a big file from AWS S3 and performing AWS DynamoDB operations in the meantime. Therefore, this whole operation takes nearly 15 minutes. The socket timeout exception is thrown somewhere around the 12-minute mark. This happens in a Mac computer.
Findings

Testes the same code in Windows 10 computer - Successful
Tested the same code in Windows 11 computer - Failed


# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007fffca2c3595, pid=7616, tid=15604
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (17.0.8+9) (build 17.0.8+9-LTS-211)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.8+9-LTS-211, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [AWSCRT_18362448542728980315aws-crt-jni.dll+0x13595]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\XXX\IdeaProjects\XXX\POC\CRT Issue\demo\demo\hs_err_pid7616.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.



Tested the same code in amazoncorretto:17 (This image should be glibc compatible) Docker container - Issue Reproduced


Caused by: java.io.IOException: software.amazon.awssdk.crt.http.HttpException: socket is closed.
        at software.amazon.awssdk.http.crt.internal.response.CrtResponseAdapter.onFailedResponseComplete(CrtResponseAdapter.java:137)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.http.crt.internal.response.CrtResponseAdapter.onResponseComplete(CrtResponseAdapter.java:108)
        at software.amazon.awssdk.crt.http.HttpStreamResponseHandlerNativeAdapter.onResponseComplete(HttpStreamResponseHandlerNativeAdapter.java:58)
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.crt.http.HttpException: socket is closed.
        ... 2 more
2024-04-22 16:03:11.363 ERROR 7 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[ [dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/demo] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while streaming file from S3 because JSON object could not be parsed] with root cause

software.amazon.awssdk.crt.http.HttpException: socket is closed.
        at software.amazon.awssdk.http.crt.internal.response.CrtResponseAdapter.onResponseComplete(CrtResponseAdapter.java:108) ~[aws-crt-client-2.21.39.jar!/:na] at software.amazon.awssdk.crt.http.HttpStreamResponseHandlerNativeAdapter.onResponseComplete(HttpStreamResponseHandlerNativeAdapter.java:58) ~[aws-crt-0.28.11.jar!/:0.28.11]



Focused on the /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time in Linux and sysctl net.inet.tcp.keepidle in Mac. By default the timeout values is 120 minutes (2 hours).

Attempted to increase timeout values in AwsCrtAsyncHttpClient and ClientOverrideConfiguration but it did not work.


I've noticed that the issue I'm encountering isn't happening on Windows 10, but it does on other operating systems. Given that the CRT client relies on C libraries, I understand that differences between operating systems could be causing this variability. To standardize the implementation and resolve the issue, I'm seeking a solution that ensures consistent behavior across all platforms. Thank you!
